# How do I resolve: Unmet dependencies in Linux Mint 21.1 x86_64

Tags: linux-mint

Os: Linux Mint 21.1 x86_64, kernel: 5.15.0-60-generic.

Problem: when I try to do; sudo apt install, sudo apt-get install, sudo apt upgrade, sudo apt-upgrade, sudo apt remove, sudo apt auto remove, sudo apt purge, sudo apt --fix-broken install and sudo apt-get install -f linux-tools-common

I always get these type of errors:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.15.0-60.66_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/acpidbg', which is also in package linux-intel-iotg-tools-common 5.15.0-1023.28
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.15.0-60.66_all.deb
```

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

This all started when I attempted to install two packages including 'linux-tools-common' because the terminal advised me to install them since I try to use 'cpupower' commands.

edit: when I ran sudo dpkg --configure -a
I get this output:

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-tools-5.15.0-60:
linux-tools-5.15.0-60 depends on linux-tools-common; however:
Package linux-tools-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-tools-5.15.0-60 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-tools-5.15.0-60-generic:
linux-tools-5.15.0-60-generic depends on linux-tools-5.15.0-60; however:
Package linux-tools-5.15.0-60 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-tools-5.15.0-60-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-tools-5.15.0-60
linux-tools-5.15.0-60-generic